# Multiple email validations through inputs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

```
<script>
    
    function validate()
    {
        var str1;
        var str2;
        if(str1==str2)
        {
            alert("email1 and email 2 are matching");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("emails do not match");
        }
        
    }
        
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" name="str1"  /><br>Email 1</br>
<input type="text" name="str2"  /><br>Email 2</br>

<!-- want to implement remaining email id has to check with each other
 and make a alert to show the duplicate. -->
<input type="text" name="str3"  /><br>Email 3</br>
<input type="text" name="str4"  /><br>Email 4</br>
<input type="text" name="input5"  /><br>Email 5</br>
<input type="text" name="input6"  /><br>Email 6</br>
<input type="text" name="input7"  /><br>Email 7</br>
<input type="text" name="input8"  /><br>Email 8</br>

<br></br>
<input type="submit" onclick="validate();" value="submit" />

</form>
```

I want to make a compare to every input element with each other and making a alert when the two ids got matched;
email validation code I know but this kind of comparison I need.

In other way says like in a text area which allows a bulk of mail ids to enter and validating if any to mail id's got matched and displaying.

Comment: get them into array, sort and iterate

Comment: hi zerkams,, im new to coding can u give me some supporting links or examples

Comment: links for what? decouple tasks to a smaller ones and solve them iteratively. I've provided you a 3-step solution. What step are you stuck on?

Comment: im looking to give a unique id t  every input and then trying to go for array , but pragmatically i got stacked in giving unique id and assigning them to array